# Parse Query wherekey: containedIn: does not work

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to sync phone contacts with parse user.

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query]; 
[userQuery whereKey:@"username" containedIn:phones];
```

It was showing me results till I added a new phone number tried again and the query seems not to get correct result as it is not bring a new user in my phone contact.

Comment: No that's not the issue.

Comment: The issue was I was creating the user with Masterkey in cloud code and the user himself had read/write permissions. That's why user was not being compared at all